# Test the convergence of $\int_1^2\frac{e^{-nt}}{t}.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Test the convergence of the sequence :
>   $$y_n=\int_1^2\frac{e^{-nt}}{t}.$$

First I show that $\frac{e^{-nt}}{t}$ is uniformly convergent and then $\lim_ny_n=0$ and so $\{y_n\}$ is convergent. Am I correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrand is bounded by 1, hence the dominated convergence theorem shows that $y_n \to 0$.